# i want to remove any from this catch block , below is my code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, error-handling, try-catch

```js
const apiCallingFunction = async (data: any) =\> {
  try {
    let response = await axiosPost("/api", { ...data });
    return response;
  } catch (err: any) {
    return err.response;
  }
};
```

I want to remove any from the catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { AxiosError } from "axios";

const apiCallingFunction = async (data: any) => {
  try {
  let response = await axiosPost("/api", { ...data });
  return response;
  } catch (err: unknown) {
   return (err as AxiosError).response;
  }
 };
```

Axios Has Inbuilt Type for error Known As AxiosError

Comment: Have you tried compiling that code? That breaks ts(1196) `Catch clause variable type annotation must be 'any' or 'unknown' if specified.`

Comment: sorry my bad have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "remove `any` from catch block" is a good practice for this problem, since anything that goes into catch block should be unexpected error, which should be typed as `unknown`. For reference, this practice has been discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36775), in the official github of Typescript.

I would recommend you to just leave the catch block `catch(err) { // some code }` without adding type to it if you are using Typescript >4.4 (explain in [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41013))